# I accidentally shorted my SPARKFUN ESP32 THING's (13907) 3v3 and ground pins

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I wanted test an led and therefore I connected across 3v3 and ground pins of Sparkfun ESP32 Thing, expecting it to have a pull up / pull down resistor. But to my surprise i blew my led besides blowing up the power indicator led of ESP32. So, when i try to upload any code like blink to it, it is saying

Connecting...__...connecting....____...

And ultimately it's throwing a fatal error. But my ESP32 is being detected in COM port list of arduino IDE

Any help to fix this is highly appreciated  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably blew the 3.3V regulator or the diode before it. You can find them in the power and filtering section of the following schematic: https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/41630.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I want to fix it

Comment: The only way to fix it is to replace the faulty components. But there is no guarantee that you did not blow the ESP32 too. But I personally think that it should be ok. The reason that your board is showing on the com list is that the USB to serial converter is powered directly with 5V USB power. But the program will never load since your computer can not verify written data. The reason for this is that your ESP32 is not even powered if you really have a blown power supply part of the board.

Comment: Will that's quite informative! I guess only buying a new board is option, anyway thanks man! Happy stacking

Comment: As I said you could simply try replacing the diode and the regulator. If that does not fix it you have blown ESP32 chip. I would give it a try if I was you.

Comment: Do you know how to upload the code, when my device gets powered on by lipo battery?

Comment: You can just program it, as usual, assuming that the regulator is still working. Your USB to serial is powered by USB. And your ESP32 will be powered by battery via the regulator if your regulator still works and the diode is the only faulty thing.